# Ex's and Oh's : What is "Oh's"?

Tags: meaning, metaphors

What does "Oh's" mean in the pop song "Ex's and Oh's" by Elle King?
http://www.metrolyrics.com/exs-ohs-lyrics-elle-king.html
I'm not asking any interpretations of lyrics, but would like to know what Oh/Ohs means as the word itself and if the word could be used in other context in daily life, I also want to know.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about interpreting song lyrics.

Comment: There likely are multiple meanings being alluded to in the song -- ie, some punning could be taking place.

Comment: My apologies to post an inappropriate question. But, I even didn't know that Oh could come from XO until I read the answer below, and so it was worth asking here at least for me as the ignorant. But thanks for pointing out, anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ex's and Oh's a play off the XO (hugs and kisses). I interpret the song as a lament of a lover, who while claiming that lovers will come back to him or her, knows that the lovers listed will only be received as memories. So the Oh in the song serves as a direct corollary to O in XO, the sexual memory of "OHhhh!, and the realization of lament as in "Oh, I'm alone with my memories." Now, a good singer would be able to interpret this song in their own way and project their version with their delivery, I do believe these are the three main interpretations available--though a few more to savor would be a nice addition to any listener and any singer who could incorporate more than one interpretation into their delivery should be considered an artist.

Comment: Thank you so much! Those three interpretations...they really make sense to me and I do agree that there could be and should be several different interpretations for lyrics. Thanks for your help.